# Data from HTML Form to PHP

Tags: php, html

i have my HTML file:

```
<form action="input_db.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and PHP file in the same directory:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```

Both running on a "UniServer Zero XIII" on my local windwos maschine

the problem is that the echo just not work

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
its this example from w3schools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sending the data in form with the "POST" method and you trying to get it with $_GET variable;

you can edit the form method to "get" :

```
<form action="input_db.php" method="get">
```

Or try to get the data with the $_POST["name"] variable

Answer (score 0):

You set the method to POST in the form.
So you need to use `POST["name"]` instead of `GET["name"]` in your PHP